# Problems with passing info to functions within a menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, amazon-s3

This is part of a menu I am working on. I am able to get the first selection (the number 1 selection of "coach") to work; however, I am having difficulty with all the other selections. When I select 2 in the menu I get this error:

"NameError: name 'beginner' is not defined"

I am fairly confident that I need something in the "def beginner():" section of my code, but nothing I add seems to work.

Below is my entire code. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

```
import logging
import boto3
import pprint
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def mainMenu(): 
    print("1. Are you looking for a coach? Here is their conact data.")
    print("2. Are you a beginner? Select 2 for your exersises.")
    print("3. Are you some where in the middle of your journey? Select 3 for your exersises.")
    print("4. Are you more Advanced? Select 4 for your exersises.")
    print("5. Are you hardcore and love to workout? Select 5.")
    print("6. Look at progress photos here!")
    print("7. Quit")   

    selection=int(input("Lets lose weight together!!! Please Select a Number:"))
    if selection==1: 
       coach()
    elif selection==2:
         beginner()
    elif selection==3: 
        intermediate()
    elif selection==4: 
       advanced()
    elif selection==5: 
        hardcore()
    elif selection==6: 
        progress_Photos()
    elif selection==7: 
        exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid choice. Enter 1-7")
        while selection == 7:
            break
        mainMenu()
    selection=int(input("Lets lose weight together!!! Please Select a Number:"))
"""Selection number 1 Input user data into DynamoDB database """
def coach():
       dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
       table = dynamodb.Table('coachdata')
       response = table.scan()
       pprint.pprint(response, depth=3, compact = True)
mainMenu()
"""Selection number 2 Calculate exersises for beginners """     
def beginner():
    poundsToLose = input("How many pounds would you like to lose this month? ")
    pushups = '2'
    situps = '10'
    plankseconds = '10'
    pushupexersises = poundsToLose * pushups 
    situpexersises = poundsToLose * situps
    plankexersises = poundsToLose * plankseconds
    answer = 
    return answer
    print ("To lose {} pound this month do {} pushups {} situps and {} planks every day.".format(poundsToLose,pushupexersises,situpexersises,plankexersises))
mainMenu()    
"""Selection number 3 Calculate exersises for intermediate users"""      
def intermediate():
    poundsToLose = input("How many pounds would you like to lose this month? ")
    pushups = '5'
    situps = '10'
    plankseconds = '10'
    pushupexersises = poundsToLose * pushups 
    situpexersises = poundsToLose * situps
    plankexersises = poundsToLose * plankseconds
    print ("To lose (poundsToLose) pound this month do (pushupexersises) pushups (situpexersises) situps and (plankexersises) planks every day.")
mainMenu()       
"""Selection number 4 Calculate exersises for advanced users"""
def advanced():
    poundsToLose = input("How many pounds would you like to lose this month? ")
    pushups = '10'
    situps = '20'
    plankseconds = '20'
    pushupexersises = poundsToLose * pushups 
    situpexersises = poundsToLose * situps
    plankexersises = poundsToLose * plankseconds
    print ("To lose (poundsToLose) pound this month do (pushupexersises) pushups (situpexersises) situps and (plankexersises) planks every day.")
mainMenu()      
"""Selection number 5 Calculate exersises for hardcore users"""   
def hardcore():
    poundsToLose = input("How many pounds would you like to lose this month? ")
    pushups = '20'
    situps = '30'
    plankseconds = '30'
    pushupexersises = poundsToLose * pushups 
    situpexersises = poundsToLose * situps
    plankexersises = poundsToLose * plankseconds
    print ("To lose (poundsToLose) pound this month do (pushupexersises) pushups (situpexersises) situps and (plankexersises) planks every day.")
mainMenu()       
"""Selection number upload progress photos to S3 """     
def progress_Photos(bucket_name, object_name):
    """Retrieve an object from an Amazon S3 bucket

    :param bucket_name: string
    :param object_name: string
    :return: botocore.response.StreamingBody object. If error, return None.
    """

    # Retrieve the object
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        # AllAccessDisabled error == bucket or object not found
        logging.error(e)
        return None
    # Return an open StreamingBody object
    return response['Body']


def mainGet():
 """Exercise get_object()"""

    # Assign these values before running the program
test_bucket_name = 'edu.umuc.sdev400.rharner.letsworkout'
test_object_name = 'beforeandafter.PNG'

    # Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format='%(levelname)s: %(asctime)s: %(message)s')

    # Retrieve the object
stream = progress_Photos(test_bucket_name, test_object_name)
if stream is not None:
        # Read first chunk of the object's contents into memory as bytes
        data = stream.read(amt=1024)

        # Output object's beginning characters
        logging.info(f'{test_object_name}: {data[:60]}...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainMenu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `mainMenu` under each function definition.

```py
"""Selection number 1 Input user data into DynamoDB database """
def coach():
       dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
       table = dynamodb.Table('coachdata')
       response = table.scan()
       pprint.pprint(response, depth=3, compact = True)

mainMenu()  # <-- here


"""Selection number 2 Calculate exersises for beginners """     
def beginner():
    ...
```

You execute `mainMenu` before the definition of all the other functions, so only `coach` is defined.

Remove those calls to `mainMenu` to only keep the one at the end:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainMenu()
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked great and I got 2-5 sorted. 6 gave this, Lets lose weight together!!! Please Select a Number:6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/letsWorkOut.py", line 124, in <module>
    mainMenu()
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/letsWorkOut.py", line 28, in mainMenu
    progress_Photos()
TypeError: progress_Photos() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'bucket_name' and 'object_name'
 would you happen to know where I screwed up on this?

Comment: That's another question. The error is explicit. `def progress_Photos(bucket_name, object_name):` (<-- args required) while `progress_Photos()` <-- no arg in call. You should review the whole design.